# Using row.setValue with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor gives 'int' object has no attribute 'setValue'

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am adding a new field to my attribute table, and trying to populate it with a a section that is already in the attribute table but converted to km instead of inches. My code does not work with either the index [1] or [0] giving me the error

> list index out of range

and

> 'int' object has no attribute 'setValue'

Here is my code:

```
target= ["C", "RW", "LW"] #positional query
height = "height"
weight= "weight"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Roster", "Center", "position = '"+target[0]+"'")
arcpy.AddField_management("Center", "heightkm", "FLOAT")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Center", "height_km") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
    row.setValue("height_km", row.getValue("height") * 2.54)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few things going on here that don't seem right.

Firstly, you're adding a field called "heightkm" but then you try to update "height_km".

Secondly, and this could just be a copy/paste artifact, but your code under your for loop isn't indented.

Finally, you're using the wrong syntax for the data access [arcpy.da.UpdateCursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm). You seem to be mixing syntax from the [old update cursor](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/updatecursor.htm) (which is much slower than the data access update cursor). You will need to add the attribute that contains the values you need in your update cursor. Presumably, that is called "height". You can do that like this:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Center", ["height","height_km"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0] * 2.54 #this is not the correct conversion, see below
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

You may also want to check your conversion as there are not 2.54km in an inch.

Comment: you are correct in the conversion, I wasn't reading clearly, it was inches to cm.